# Zend Studio 5 - HTML5

Tags: php, html, zend-studio

My Zend Studio 5 has a feature where it reports broken HTML or invalid tags in red.

As ZS5 was developed before HTML5,  and  tags are showing as broken.

Does anyone know if there is some kind of XML file containing the list of valid HTML tags that I could append the newly created HTML5 tags to.

Thanks.

Comment: *(tipp)* consider asking in the [official Zend Forums](http://forums.zend.com/viewforum.php?f=50) too or open a ticket if you still got a valid support subscription.

Comment: @Gordon - thanks i have created a thread there: http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=8398

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that will have a fix. It already been deprecated (now it's a plugin of Eclipse). May I recommend you that join the blue side of the IDEs ? Installing Eclipse & PDT. You will notice that ZS5 it's old when trying to use PHP5's `namespace`. I've made the change.

Comment: Agreed. ZS5 is still my favourite IDE, but it's getting dated.